# What are benefits of running Java on Linux (moving away from Windows)

Tags: java, windows, linux

I am currently running a large distributed Java system on Windows.

What are benefits of moving to Linux - from a Java point of view?

One I can think of is being able to run 'services' natively.  At the moment I have to log in to the Windows box and start the Java program.

Are there performance gains, etc.?

Comment: Services can run on Windows too.  Check the winsw service wrapper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no major Java-specific advantages, the JVMs are pretty much the same.

You get the usual advantages of having a Unix-like operating system however. Many of those advantages boil down to familiarity or re-usability however, since Windows has slowly caught up with many of those:

- easy, pretty standardized scripting: pretty much every unix-based OS has a POSIX compatible shell (Windows got the PowerShell, however)
- easy, standardized, secure remote access (SSH)
- ...

Comment: Disclaimer: I much prefer running Java on Linux and still think it's better than running on Windows. But the difference is no longer as obvious as it was a few years ago. Now it's more about "what is your operation team more comfortable with?" than anything else.

Comment: can you elaborate more differences @Joachim Sauer,I had a similar interview question asked once.

Comment: I don't know why, but in fact Java runs way faster on Linux than on Windows. Compiling an Hybris project on Linux (Ubuntu mate 16.04) took 1/4 of the time required on Windows 10 and 1/2 for server start up. Same JDK (Oracle, 1.8.0_144) and same computer.

Answer (score 2):

One potential benefit, the windows timer can be problematic (you can find many posts via google around this issue).

One good resource [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks).

Answer (score 1):

[Linux runs Java faster than Windows](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/1050112/linux-runs-java-faster-windows)
 also see [Java Performance: Ubuntu Linux vs. Windows Vista](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=java_vm_performance&num=1)

Comment: Your references are comparing running Java on notebooks. I don't think that he will run a large distributed application on notebooks. And i think there is a significant diference when java runs on "PC's" or "servers". Anyway your reference is interesting.

Comment: Also: they compare 1.6u7 on Windows with 1.6u10 on Linux. Update 10 was a pretty big upgrade, so it's not even comparing equivalent versions.

Comment: Also its Vista. Sorry but any Microsoft solution was better than vista (aka longhorn) that includes Bob and Windows ME. 

Now, while phoronix is spot on with their benchmarks most if not all of those issues have been fixed in JVM 1.8 and there would need to be a apples-apples comparison done with modern hardware and OSs. (ie Windows Server 2008/2012 vs Linux 3.1 kernel/CentOS 7)

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line is that both Linux and Java are server oriented so they collaborate IMO more gracefully.
It's no surprise that one of the major (and very profitable) server OS is Red Hat.  It's reliable and datacenter friendly.

Whereas Windows servers are still in the area of office automation, employees herding (Active Directory, SMS), and collaboration support (Sharepoint).

On the desktop, MS folks target the broader market of non IT people. Over the years they've managed to bury IT concepts and settings deeper and deeper.  And this is counterproductive in the server area.

By developing on Linux, you build the boat next to the pier.  You won't have to work too much to carry the boat to the water... my 2 cts of course.